# StringVar.set won't work in module package

Tags: tkinter, module, package, subclassing

I'm trying to write a GUI interface to help expedite the paperwork at work. I've been creating custom classes, inheriting from tkinter's classes as well as a widget class that I've written. When I had my entire module written in one .py file, everything worked fine. Now, I've split it up into several files as a package, and it will no longer allow me to use the .set method on StringVar objects created in `widget.__init__`

```
 class widget:

    def __init__(self,master,text=None,trace=None):
        self.master = master
        self._text = StringVar(self.master,value=text)

        self._trace = trace
        self.trace = self._trace

    @property
    def text(self):
        return self._text.get()
    @text.setter
    def text(self,val):
        self._text.set(val)

    @property
    def trace(self):
        return self._trace
    @trace.setter
    def trace(self,val):
        self._trace = val
        self._text.trace('w', lambda *args, **kwargs:val(*args,**kwargs))
```

All of the widget subclasses inherit from the widget class. This allows them all to use textvariable instead of variable and for self.text to be used to get or set the text value. As I said, it worked when it was in a single module, but now that it's in a package, it gives throws:

`TclError: can't set "PY_VARX"`

Any advice is appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: There's not enough code here. We need a [mcve]. My guess is that you're creating more than one instance of `Tk`.

Comment: The 'widget' class itself must inherit properties from another tkinter base class such as an Entry. So class widget(Entry):  is probably how your widget class should be defined. Then you have to bind the StringVar to the textvariable property of the Entry. That is done by self.configure(textvariable=self._text). I agree with Bryan, there's just not enough here to understand what you really want to do.

Comment: Thanks for the advice. When trying to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example, I realized that the problem was a change I had made that somehow escaped my notice while I was troubleshooting. I was able to resolve the issue myself.

Comment: I was actually doing the inheritance in the opposite way. entry(Entry,widget) is how I was defining it. the widget class existed to give certain properties (mostly the StringVar) to widgets of all types.